# tools for generating semantic web based on ontology

Tags: rdf, semantics, jena, ontology, protege

what is the differencce between creating ontology in protege IDE and creating RDf/ontology in netbeans using jena?

i am using this tutorial  http://jena.sourceforge.net/tutorial/RDF_API/  for creating RDF in netbeans using JENA.

Answer (score 6):

It's all a matter of convenience for the person creating the ontology. Creating an ontology using Protégé doesn't require any programming knowledge, and can be quite quick and easy once you are used to the interface. However, you can't automate the process, for example converting CSV or other data sources into RDF. with Jena, it's harder work to create the ontology (you have to write Java code, not just point and click on the GUI), but the end result is easier to repeat and easier to automate.

At the end of the day, however, the ontologies created by either route are equivalent in terms of what they can express in OWL.

Comment: what exactly you mean by automating the process? i didn't get the example that you said..

Comment: Suppose you want to create an ontology using data from a spreadsheet or database. You could read what the spreadsheet says, and type or copy-paste the text into an ontology editor, like Protege. That's a manual process. Or, you could write some code that reads the spreadsheet, does some conversion computation, builds a data structure, and writes out the ontology document. That's an automated process. If you only have to create the ontology once, it may not matter. But if the spreadsheet changes and you have to redo the ontology, having an automated process makes your life easier.